# evaluation of ternary operator in php

Tags: php

```
echo strlen('Hello World') > 2 ? '...' : '' . substr('Hello World',0,2);
```

above code output:

```
...
```

what I except was

```
...He
```

Can anyone explain how the above code is evaluated in php

## **EDIT**

```
echo substr('Hello World',0,2) . strlen('Hello World') > 2 ? '...' : '';
```

OUTPUT

NO OUTPUT

BUT this works

```
echo substr('Hello World',0,2), strlen('Hello World') > 2 ? '...' : '';
```

OUTPUT

```
He...
```

Comment: You're missing some parenthesis... or you're not familiar with which side is the true/false side of the ternary.

Comment: Everything is already described in php-manual http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: Your condition is equivalent to saying:  `echo '...';`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's evaluated like this:

```
echo strlen('Hello World') > 2 ? '...' : ('' . substr('Hello World',0,2));
```

What you probably want is this:

```
echo (strlen('Hello World') > 2 ? '...' : '') . substr('Hello World',0,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The same as if-condition:

```
if(strlen('Hello World') > 2) {
    echo '...';
} else {
    echo '' . substr('Hello World',0,2);
}
```

Comment: You can simplify it further. Their if condition is equivalent to saying `echo '...';`

Comment: I just wanted to show how his code was evaluated, the mistake he did is pretty obvious. ;)